# Calling function inside another function

Tags: java

I have an error like this when I call one function inside another in Java.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The local variable n may not have been initialized

Here is my code:

```
public class SecondPart {
public static double Factr(double n){
    int i,fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){      
    return fact=fact*i;
    }
}       

public static double ArcSinh(double x){
    double n;

        return Factr(n);

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(ArcSinh(6.0));

    }

 }
```

Comment: Do what the error message suggests that you do -- initialize the offending variable.  The error message will tell you which one it is -- initialize it to a default value when you declare it. And never try to run code that doesn't compile (as you're currently doing).

Comment: what is n in your method `public static double ArcSinh(double x)`

Comment: change to return Factr(x);

Comment: public static double ArcSinh(double x){
 //   double n; delete this line
        return Factr(x); // pass x to Factr method
}

Comment: @NickZiebert Doesn't work!

Comment: @JayanandRaghuwanshi Doesn't work!

Comment: Ah, the other thing wrong is your factor method.  should be this:  

public static double Factr(double n){
    int i,fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){      
   fact=fact*i;
    }
 return factor;
}

Do the first thing I said to did too.  My output is 720.0